# GCM push notification not received (gone through all)

Tags: android, asp.net, rest, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Before you point this as a duplicate, I know this has been asked many a times but it seems after the launch of new GCM (that which requires one to include play services project as library) [things have changed on how to correctly implement gcm in our code](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html).

The breakpoint in my `GCMIntentService.java` and `GcmBroadcastReceiver.java` gets hit on register since I have set `<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />` in the manifest but the breakpoints don't get hit when i send a push from the server. Here's all which you would ever need:

### Relevant `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.aceast.waveindia"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="waveindia1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.aceast.waveindia.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />



 <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.aceast.waveindia" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
```

### `GCMBroadcastReceiver.java`

```
    public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
//breakpoint gets hit on register here...
            ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                    GcmIntentService.class.getName());
            // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
            startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
            setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        }
    }
```

### Part of GCMIntentService which breakpoint hits on `register`

```
 @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
```

### `.NET code` which triggers push

```
public string SendNotification()
    {

        var value = Message;
        WebRequest tRequest;
        tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        tRequest.Method = "post";
        tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
       // tRequest.ContentType = " application/json;charset=UTF-8";
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", GOOGLE_APPID));

        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

        string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + DeviceID + "";
        Console.WriteLine(postData);
        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

        dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();


        tReader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        tResponse.Close();
        return sResponseFromServer;
    }
```

### Local firewall has 5228-5230 ports unblocked

Now can you point the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a problem in your manifest :

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.aceast.waveindia.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Should be :

```
<permission android:name="com.aceast.waveindia.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.aceast.waveindia.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```